# overriding imported functions?

Tags: python, function, overriding

Why am I able to override an imported function when using `import module` but not when using `from module import *`? eg:

**file1.py**

```
def f1():
    print('f1')

def main():
    f1()
```

**file2.py**

```
import file1

def f2():
    print('f2')

file1.f1 = f2
file1.main()
# result is 'f2'
```

**file3.py**

```
from file1 import *

def f3():
    print('f3')

f1 = f3
main()
# result is 'f1'
```

Comment: Because you aren't overriding that module's version of it, just shadowing the name *in the current module*.

Comment: is there a way to explicitly override rather than shadow?

Comment: Yes: by importing the module not the function.

Comment: ...which you have already demonstrated.

Comment: Override isn't really the correct word here...

Comment: In **file3.py** you're changing the what `f1` was set to by the `import *` to `f3`, but that doesn't change the `f1` being used inside **file1.py**.